# add alternative IP address to kubernetes api server

Tags: kubernetes, certificate, tls1.2

I'm trying to connect to kubernetes cluster deployed by kubeadm on AWS lightsail instances (Master & 2 worker nodes). I copied the .kube/config file to my local machine and replaced the `server: https://172.26.2.101:6443` with `server: https://<public_ip_address>:6443` and tried to connect. but got below error

```
Unable to connect to the server: x509: certificate is valid for 10.96.0.1, 172.26.2.101, not <public_ip_address>
```

Any ideas ?!

Thanks,

Comment: did you try this https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/07/30/adding-a-name-to-kubernetes-api-server-certificate/ ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution below,

remove current apiserver certificates

```
sudo rm /etc/kubernetes/pki/apiserver.*
```

generate new certificates adding the public ip

```
sudo kubeadm init phase certs apiserver --apiserver-cert-extra-sans=<public_ip>
```